# Django ModelForm does not save in database

Tags: python, django

I am trying to make a simple to-do list in Django that each user could have their own task list so when they logged in they add a task and its save for themselves and the list only display their own tasks, but when I try to add a task from the template's form it won't save but when I add task manually from admin panel it work.

my **models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Tasks(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    check = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import *

class TaskForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Tasks
        fields = '__all__'
```

**views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .forms import *
from .models import Tasks


@login_required(login_url = 'login')
def tasks(request):
    tasks = Tasks.objects.filter(user = request.user)
    context = { 'tasks': tasks }
    return render(request,'ToDo/list.html',context)

@login_required(login_url = 'login')
def add_task(request):
    form = TaskForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TaskForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save(commit=False)
            form.user = request.user
            form.save()
        return redirect('/')
    context = {'form' : form}
    return render(request,'ToDo/add.html',context)
```

where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You assign the user to the `.user` attribute of the *form*, not of the `.instance` wrapped in the form. You thus should alter the instance with:

```
@login_required(login_url = 'login')
def add_task(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TaskForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.user = request.user
            form.save()
            return redirect('/')
    else:
        form = TaskForm()
    return render(request, 'ToDo/add.html', {'form' : form})
```

You should furthermore *only* redirect in case of a *successful* POST request: in case the POST request is not successful, the form can render the error messages, and thus will inform the user what the problem is.

Furthermore you make the `user` field non-editable:

```
from django.conf import settings

class Tasks(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        editable=False,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    check = models.BooleanField(default = False)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).